# Is there a way to catch exception of a deferred constraint in pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, exception, constraints, plpgsql

Consider the following code:

```
drop table if exists demo cascade;
drop table if exists child cascade;

create table demo
(
    id bigint not null 
    constraint demo_pk primary key
);

create table child
(
    id bigint not null 
        constraint child_pk primary key,
    pid bigint,
        constraint child_pid_fk
        foreign key (pid)
        references demo (id)
        deferrable initially deferred  -- remove this line and exceptions get caught
);

insert into demo values (1);
insert into child values (11, 1);

do language plpgsql $$
begin
    delete from demo where id = 1;
exception
    when others then
        raise notice 'exception caught';
end;
$$;
```

I would like to catch any exception thrown by constraints, but for performance reasons I defer checking constraints until commit (`deferrable initially deferred`). Is there a way to catch exceptions without turning `immediate` mode on?

Comment: No, you can't because by definition deferred constraint are not checked until you commit. You will need to deal with the exception in the code running that SQL

Comment: You could try and run `SET CONSTRAINTS child_pid_fk IMMEDIATE;` after the `DELETE` statement, in SQL context that triggers the constraint check; however I'm not sure if that's true in plpgsql context too. -- Edit: just saw you wrote that you seek options other than this. I don't think there are other options.

Comment: @pozs: I think you were on the right track after all. I think the OP just does not want to change the table definition, `SET CONSTRAINTS` is what he needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* set deferrable constraints to `IMMEDIATE` just for your transaction without *"turning immediate mode on"* (without changing the constraint definition).

That's exactly what this separate command [**`SET CONSTRAINTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html) is for:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS child_pid_fk IMMEDIATE;
```

Or if you don't know constraint name(s):

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html)

> `SET CONSTRAINTS` sets the behavior of constraint checking **within the current transaction**.

Bold emphasis mine.

And:

> When `SET CONSTRAINTS` changes the mode of a constraint from
> `DEFERRED` to `IMMEDIATE`, the new mode takes effect retroactively:
> any outstanding data modifications that would have been checked at the
> end of the transaction are instead checked during the execution of the
> `SET CONSTRAINTS` command. If any such constraint is violated, the
> `SET CONSTRAINTS` fails (and does not change the constraint mode).
> Thus, `SET CONSTRAINTS` can be used to force checking of constraints
> to occur at a specific point in a transaction.

Exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks. PostgreSQL seems to be smart enough not to check the same constraints again and again when I switch from DEFERRED to IMMEDIATE and back multiple times in the same transaction. I checked empirically by measuring time that each time I switch to IMMEDIATE, only updated rows are checked.